# how to get last n results by updated time in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, bigdata, nosql

I want to fetch last n, say last 5 updated rows i.e. order by updated_time desc in cassandra. Is there any good way of doing it?

Exact use case is like, I want to update the count of event whenever it occurs in the event table and fetch the last five events by updated time along with the count.

table structure:-

event_name text, updated_time timestamp, count counter

Answer (score 0):

In Cassandra you can retrieve the editing time with `writetime (cell_name)`. But as you have multiple columns and Cassandra is fast-reads only you may consider doing another view providing exactly the data needed in an ordered manner. On that new table you want to limit read results and periodically trim it down.

It may be possible doing it with `writetime()` -- but this was not the Cassandra way as it is too slow in production. Another table with just your data is the denormalized Cassandra way of solving it.